# Python regular expression with different levels of greedyness

Tags: python, regex

I want to extract the ip address from following string with Python re

```
"aa:xv172.31.2.27bb,"
```

Using the following pattern

```
ip_address = re.sub(r'.*([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}).*',
                    r'\1',ip_address)
```

results in

```
2.31.2.27
```

because the first operator is as greedy as possible. I want the ip address matcher to be "more greedy" to get the full ip address. How to do this?

Comment: why have the first and last matchers at all, if you are just using the middle part? (re.search instead of re.sub would work better)

Comment: Just using the middle part results in replacing the middle part by the middle part., i.e. I get the original string back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `re.search` when you want to extract something:

```py
>>> s = "aa:xv172.31.2.27bb,"
>>> re.search(r'\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,3}){3}', s)[0]
'172.31.2.27'
```

If you want to know how to do it with `re.sub` for this case, use non-greedy for the first `.*`:

```py
>>> re.sub(r'.*?(\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,3}){3}).*', r'\1', s)
'172.31.2.27'
```

`\d` isn't the right way to match IP address range. You can either construct the pattern yourself, or use a module such as https://github.com/madisonmay/CommonRegex (this one uses `25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?` which can be further simplified, but you get the idea).

See also: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/ipaddress.html